# What radius best represents reaction distance?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, molecules, intermolecular-forces, atomic-radius

Molecules must be within a certain distance for a reaction to begin as well as satisfying a myriad of other factors. Whilst the exact distance varies from reaction to reaction, is their any distance/molecular radius which provides a fairly good picture in terms of how close the centre of the molecules have to be to begin the interaction given they are in the correct orientation with enough energy etc.?

Comment: I suspect this depends on the kind of molecules involved: there's atomic, ionic, covalent, Van der Waals radius, etc.

Comment: I understand but I was wondering if there is sort of an 'effective' radius where 9 times out of 10 they will interact for all reactions that can be used for calculations.